# CursorAdapter can't resolve RatingBar

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, findviewbyid, ratingbar

While trying to create a custom cursor adapter, I'm baffled why 3 out of 4 views can and 1 view can't be found when trying to assign view.findViewById.

Here's (part of) my CursorAdapter, which can find the 2 TextViews and 1 ImageView in "activity_main_list_item.xml", but somehow get an error for the RatingBar: `Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_main_list_item_ratingbar'`:

```
public class FlavorCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    public FlavorCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_main_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView nameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_list_item_tv_name);
        TextView shortDescriptionTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_list_item_tv_description_short);
        ImageView cupImageImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_list_item_iv_cup_image);
        RatingBar flavorRatingBar = view.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_list_item_ratingbar);
```

Here's the related "activity_main_list_item.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_list_item_iv_cup_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_main_lv_list_item_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_main_lv_list_item_height"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cup_image"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cup_unknown" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_list_item_tv_name"
        style="@style/flavor_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/activity_main_list_item_tv_description_short"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/activity_main_list_item_iv_cup_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_main_list_item_iv_cup_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/activity_main_list_item_iv_cup_image"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_list_item_tv_description_short"
        style="@style/flavor_name_sub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/flavor_description_short"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/activity_main_list_item_iv_cup_image"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/activity_main_list_item_iv_cup_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_main_list_item_iv_cup_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_main_list_item_tv_name"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_list_item_ratingbar"
        style="@style/flavor_ratingbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:rating="2.5"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I must be overlooking something really simple here, but cannot see it.
Can someone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it actually build and run? Android Studio is sometimes lazy in synchronizing generated code with suggestions.

Comment: Wow, I'm certain I spent 15-30mins trying and it wouldn't work... indeed, now it does, so Android Studio must've been lazy. Although I'm not a very experienced programmer, I hadn't seen this happen yet. Could I have forced it to work by simply making Studio 'Rebuild Project'?

Comment: Rebuilding from scratch is a waste of time in this case (imagine having multi-module project with tens of thousands lines of code), the best you can do is to ignore it. It compiles OK, so the only problem is with the suggestions, which you don't need at this point, because you wrote the whole identifier yourself.